# debugging class members - ReferenceError: myPanel is not defined

Tags: gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I am using Chrome dev tools to step through my GWT MVP app as it renders a View using Super Dev Mode.

In the developer tools, I am stepping though the source mapped java code executing my method.
I can highlight variables, right click, and "Evaluate in console" to inspect the state of my locally scoped variables.

I want to do the same things with my class members.
It works in public methods. Within private methods, evaluating a class member results in a "ReferenceError:  is not defined." response.

I tried annotating my class members with "this.myPanel". The response is a simple "undefined". Besides 'this' is referencing Window[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `this$static`
It's the object holding the members and state of instances passed as argument to functions that used to be class members but GWT compiles them to regular js functions

## static members

GWT will convert static functions to just functions (not under any object in js)

```java
public class SomeEntry implements EntryPoint {
    public static String Moo() {
        String href = Window.Location.getHref();
        return href.substring(5, 10);
    }
    public static String Moo(String x) {
        String href = Window.Location.getHref();
        return href.substring(5, 10);
    }
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        Window.alert(Moo());
        Window.alert(Moo("asd"));
    }
}
```

Will be compiled to:

```js
function Moo(){
  var href_0;
  href_0 = getHref();
  return $substring_0(href_0, 5, 10);
}

function Moo_0(){
  var href_0;
  href_0 = getHref();
  return $substring_0(href_0, 5, 10);
}
```

So overloading which is resolved at compile time will work in JS. This has the benefit of not requiring referral using the dot operator. Each dot is a new lookup.

Comment: Thanks for the this$static. for referencing members from private methods. Do you know how to access static class variables?

Comment: Static is probably converted to no namespace (in closure scope) to improve performance by not using "namespace" (dot operator). But I can't verify it. It's just a guess.